# Shall we store JWT as a cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, token, jwt

I am considering replacing my old `session-cookie-based` authentication with `JWT` token-based authentication. I read from [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/) that it is suggested to store JWT as cookie.

If so, isn't that a re-implementation of `signed cookie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is but the advantage is that the format (i.e. JSON), some of the information elements (expiry timestamp, issued-at timestamp, issuer etc.) and the method of protecting it (i.e. signature/encryption method) is standardized so you can use stock libraries to create and read it in a very convenient and error-free way.